# Vimalakirti Sutra -- A License for Drinking and Visiting Brothels?

Tags: sexuality, relationship, desire, sexual-misconduct

I have heard from the Vimalakirti Sutra that Vimalakirti was a householder who drank and visited prostitutes; but he was foremost in wisdom and Buddhist practice?!

I heard the Buddha sent monks to him to observe and study under his guidance?! Is this true?! Why would the Buddha do this?!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the translation below, it sounds like [Vimalakirti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimalakirti) intentionally tried to bring Buddhist teachings to the brothels and cabarets, rather than him being enlightened in spite of frequenting brothels and cabarets.

From the [Vimalakirti Nirdesa Sutra](https://www2.kenyon.edu/Depts/Religion/Fac/Adler/Reln260/Vimalakirti.htm), translated by [Prof. Robert Thurman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Thurman):

> He made his appearance at the fields of sports and in the casinos, but
> his aim was always to mature those people who were attached to games
> and gambling. He visited the fashionable heterodox teachers, yet
> always kept unswerving loyalty to the Buddha. He understood the
> mundane and transcendental sciences and esoteric practices, yet always
> took pleasure in the delights of the Dharma. He mixed in all crowds,
> yet was respected as foremost of all.
>
> In order to be in harmony with people, he associated with elders, with
> those of middle age, and with the young, yet always spoke in harmony
> with the Dharma. He engaged in all sorts of businesses, yet had no
> interest in profit or possessions. To train living beings, he would
> appear at crossroads and on street corners, and to protect them he
> participated in government. To turn people away from the Hinayana and
> to engage them in the Mahayana, he appeared among listeners and
> teachers of the Dharma. To develop children, he visited all the
> schools. **To demonstrate the evils of desire, he even entered the
> brothels. To establish drunkards in correct mindfulness, he entered
> all the cabarets.**
>
> ... Thus lived the Licchavi Vimalakirti in the great city of Vaisali,
> **endowed with an infinite knowledge of skill in liberative techniques**.